# Cubic Root in python without using the power operator

Tags: python

I need your help in the following question

Print the greatest integer whose cube is smaller or equal to the input number without using the power operator ,you must use the print function and match the expected output :

- **Print** the following for input **n=99**:
  4,not exact with difference 35
- **Print** the following for input **n=2000**:
  12,not exact with difference 272
- **Print** the following for input **n=1000**:
  10, exact!

  ```
  def cubic_root(n):
        if n<0:
           n=abs(n)
           cube_root = n**(1/3)*(-1)
        else:
            cube_root = n**(1/3)
            diff = round(n-(cube_root *cube_root *cube_root ))
            print (cube_root,"not exact with",diff)
    return cube_root

  print(round(cubic_root(99))) 
  print(round(cubic_root(2000))) 
  print(round(cubic_root(1000)))
  ```

My output:

```
4 not exact with 35
4
12 not exact with 272
12
9 not exact with 271
9
```

Comment: Your code is using exponentiation - please edit the code of your attempt to avoid exponentiation into your question and explain what’s wrong with the output you get.

Comment: Make a guess, check that x\*x\*x < n.  You can make several guesses using a loop or a binary search.  Presumably for the numbers you're being tested on, it'll be very fast.

Comment: Personally, I would build a list of the first 1000 or so cubes `cubes = [x*x*x for x in range(1000)]`. Then use that to find the answer. Rebuilding if needed.

Comment: Your last example fails because of rounding.  Python does fractional powers using either logarithms or a Taylor series, so the answer is not exactly 10.0.  You can try rounding the result first (`cubr_root = round(n**(1/3))`), but since that uses the power operator, that violates your spec.  You need a simple iterative approach that starts with the answer and finds the closest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With binary search the solution could look like this:

```
def cubicRoot(n):
    if n < 2:
        print(f"{n}, exact!")
    else:
        low = 0
        high = n
        while low < high:
            mid = (low + high) // 2
            if mid * mid * mid > n:
                high = mid
            else:
                low = mid + 1
        root = low - 1
        diff = n - root * root * root
        if diff:
            print(f"{root}, not exact with difference {diff}")
        else:
            print(f"{root}, exact!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def cubic_root(n):
    n=abs(n)
    result=1
    x=2
    if n==0:
        print('0, exact!')
    elif n==1:
        print('1, exact!')
    else:
        while result<n:
            result=x*x*x
            if result>=n:
                break
            x=x+1
        if result!=n:
            x=x-1
        diff=(x*x*x)-n
        if diff==0:
            print('{0}, exact!'.format(str(x)))
        else:
            diff=abs(diff)
            print('{0}, not exact with difference {1}'.format(str(x), str(diff)))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

def cubic_root(n):

```
n=abs(n)
result=1
x=2
if n==0:
    print('0, exact!')
elif n==1:
    print('1, exact!')
else:
    while result<n:
        result=x*x*x
        if result>=n:
            break
        x=x+1
    if result!=n:
        x=x-1
    diff=(x*x*x)-n
    if diff==0:
        print('{0}, exact!'.format(str(x)))
    else:
        diff=abs(diff)
        print('{0}, not exact with difference {1}'.format(str(x), str(diff)))
```

n = int(input("enter the value: "))
cubic_root(n)

##this worked for me